# Not so hidden form field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input field where users can input a comment. I want to add another field but I want it to be "hidden" where when they click "add people" a drop-down-box with an input field pops down and then you type the name of the person you would like to add. Then when the user hits 'submit' the comment and the additional "people" information gets processed by my PHP script. How would this be done?

Comment: This may not solve all of your problems, but here is a component for the auto-complete portion - http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/aJHnV/

Answer (score 1):

the "add people" drop-down-box with an input fields, will be in a hidden div.  The div could appear when an user click on the "add people".

the drop-down and the input value will always be send to your php script. In PHP, be sure to exclude any default value that you put in those fields.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to use jQuery, if that is an option.

If it's not, you can use the Javascript DOM to accomplish the same thing, just with much more effort.

You have two options for the hidden form field:

1. You can create it each time they click "add people"
2. You can create it ahead of time, and hide it by default, then just show it when someone clicks "add people".

To hide it by default, just specify the CSS attribute: `display: none` on the element you want to hide (or it's container element).

If you are using jQuery, you can bind a function to the click event of your "add people" button. Otherwise, you can specify the `onclick=""` attribute to call some Javascript function that displays the hidden input box.

Once you are ready to submit the form, you can once again, using jQuery, bind the submission of the form to a Javascript function:
`$(myform).submit(someFunction)`. Likewise, if jQuery is not an option, you can use the `onsubmit` attribute on the form to handle what happens when the form is submitted.

With some more information, I can tailor this response a little better to your needs.